# PHP get list of selected times range from pool mySQL time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, date-range

I need to get the selected time range from the a mySQL database but I'm really struggling... Basically - The list of times are:

```
id     Start        End
1      2:00         3:00
2      3:00         4:00
3      4:00         5:00
```

I selected:

```
2:00         3:00
3:00         4:00
```

**I want to get the id of the selected dates**

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT id FROM DB WHERE start_time BETWEEN '$from_time' AND '$to_time';
```

But the code doesn't work, it only gets the selected `2:00 - 3:00` time and **not** the `3:00 - 4:00` time.

When I try:

```
SELECT id FROM DB WHERE start_time >= '$from_time' AND to_time <= '$to_time';
```

I get **NO** resutls... Please help..

Comment: what is the value of `$from_time` and `$to_time`??

Comment: What are your inputs and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id from table where '$from_time' >= start_time and '$to_time' <= to_time;
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'm tired and should take a nap now haha. :)